# Wildcard * not interreted by python argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm trying to write a scrip that could take all files in a directory and allowing the user to use the  `*` to refere to multiples files.

This is the line in which I set up the parser to recive the input files:

```py
parser.add_argument('-f', '--files', help='The files to compare.', required=True, nargs='+')
```

This is the line of the error

```
Invalid argument: '.\\rmsd\\*.xyz'
```

This is the code I run to execute the script

```
python .\rsmd.py -r .\rmsd\1.xyz -f .\rmsd\*.xyz
```

My purpose is to let the user use the script in Windows and in Linux.

Comment: Works for me. Please post the _full_ traceback of your error and a [mre]. Please read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: @hostingutilities.com I'm currently on windows

Comment: What raised the 'Invalid argument' message?  It doesn't look like something that `argparse` would raise.  What did `print(args)` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, python only receives the `.\rmsd\*.xyz` as string, it doesn't evaluate which files match the pattern. you can use e.g. the `glob` module to parse that.

```py
import glob
my_txt_files = glob.glob("*.txt")  # returns list of filenames in current directory matching the pattern
# e.g.:
matched_files = glob.glob(arguments.files)
```

---

Edit for platforms:

You could check if more than one file was matched to make it more platform-independent

```
import argparse
import glob

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--files', nargs='+')
arguments = parser.parse_args()
matched_files = []
for file in arguments.files:
    if glob.escape(file) != file:
        # -> There are glob pattern chars in the string
        matched_files.extend(glob.glob(file))
    else:
        matched_files.append(file)
```

---

If you don't want to handle it in the program, you can start the program on Powershell with prior extension like this

```
python rsmd.py -f (get-childitem *.txt)
```

Comment: *"Python only receives the .\rmsd\*.xyz as string"* - this depends on the shell.  e.g. Bash expands the glob before python sees the args.

Comment: I have added the note that this is how Windows handles it and how to make it work in both (tested on Powershell, cmd and bash).

Comment: @0x5453, the OP mentions Windows, and uses backslash in this example.  Otherwise the OP is unclear as to where the error occurs